# open whatsapp chat group invite in android app

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to open whatsapp  invite link from my app.I use the following code :

```
 Intent openUrlIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    if (openUrlIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(openUrlIntent);
    }
```

When the user click the link in my app it shows loading forever
Only if the user close it then open it again it works as expected and shows the whatsapp group invite message.
Is there anyway to make it open from the first time?
I also added the queries to the manifest file for android 11 and newer versions but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after a lot of google search and observing some whatsapp related codes I have:

```
 Intent intentWhatsapp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intentWhatsapp.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    intentWhatsapp.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(intentWhatsapp);
```

Hope it helps other developers who need it